# Cronjob not echoing?

Tags: mysql, echo, cron

I have a script to check if mysql is running.

```
#!/bin/sh
SERVICE='mysql'

if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $SERVICE > /dev/null
then
    echo "$SERVICE service running, everything is fine"
else
    echo "$SERVICE is not running"
    echo "$SERVICE is not running!" | mail -s "$SERVICE down" root
fi
```

I set up cron to run it every minute.

```
1 * * * * /cronscripts/mysqlcheck
```

The script works fine when I run it manually, but it does not echo to the screen once a minute. The file is executable.

Comment: try having it print/append to a file instead.  Probably what is happening is that the cron job runs under a user other than you (and would echo to their screen, except they are probably a server thread somewhere without a "screen")

Comment: If you want it on your CLI, use `wall` or `write` or something. BTW: usually, I use something like this under Debian: `/etc/init.d/mysql status` (or, if I circumvent the init script: `. /lib/lsb/init-functions;status_of_proc "$DAEMON" "$NAME" && exit 0 || exit $?`). Does your OS not have something like sysvinit / upstart / systemd? And if so: why not use nagios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And why do you think cron manager will echo to the screen? Which exactly screen? No screen there, the file is launched from a daemon.

Check your e-mail, all this echoes should be reported as mails to root, cron or some user like this.

Edit: If you want a screen echo then try to use the screen , e.g. `echo "bla bla bla" > /dev/tty1`

Comment: root@username:/var/mail# ls -l
total 0

Comment: Then look in the cron log file (or turn it on if it is disabled)

Comment: Thanks LHristov! You're edit didn't work but it lead me to what i was looking for. Here is the new script.

#!/bin/sh
SERVICE='mysql'

if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $SERVICE > /dev/null
then
    echo "$SERVICE service running, everything is fine" > /dev/pts/0
<-- rest cut -->

Answer (score 0):

The `!` usually do some trouble in scripts when inside double quotes